# Rails: base64 and character escaping problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, escaping, uri, base64

In my app I need to encode a string via base64, escape it's possible special characters and put it into a URL.

I do the following:

```
string = "random_email@server.com"

enc = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('DES-EDE3-CBC')
enc.encrypt('dummy_salt')
encoded = URI.escape(Base64.encode64(enc.update(string) << enc.final))
```

The problem is, that somehow `URI.escape` do not escape '/' character. That's completely unacceptable if the encoded string is intended to be used as a URL parameter.

How come `URI.escape` ignores to escape '/'? Should I user any other `.escape` then one, which comes from URI? Or should I even use other encoding method (don't think so)?

Any suggestions as to the code are welcome too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CGI.escape` instead :-)

```
require 'cgi'
puts CGI.escape('/') # => "%2F"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to escape html you can also do:

```
CGI::escapeHTML('Usage: foo "bar" <baz>')

"Usage: foo &quot;bar&quot; &lt;baz&gt;"
```